# Is it possible to inject sql to delete statement?

Tags: sql-server, sql-injection

i built website that uses sql server and have this sql for deleting items by id that im getting from querystring:

```
DELETE FROM tablename WHERE GUID = 'param'
```

is it possible to inject sql that will return db_name() for example?

i know that i can inject sql only for **select** statements something like this

```
select name from tablename where 'parems' 
union all
select db_name()
```

but what about **delete** statements

i know that i can drop table insert to table, but in this stage i need know if i can get kind of data, for ex.: db_name()

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Sure. This value of param:

```
' OR ''='
```

will result in this statement:

```
DELETE FROM tablename WHERE GUID ='' OR '' = ''
```

which will delete all data in the table.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, a query always returns a result, so if the database driver allows it you can simply add another query after the delete.

An input like this:

```
x'; select db_name() --
```

would give:

```
DELETE FROM tablename WHERE GUID = 'x'; select db_name() --'
```

Answer (score 0):

You should read the [wiki](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection) & [MS docs](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms161953.aspx) on SQL Injection

Comment: You should read [The Curse and Blessings of Dynamic SQL](http://www.sommarskog.se/dynamic_sql.html) by Erland Sommarskog.

Answer (score 0):

I think your asking if its possible using purely delete statement. If so, its possible by adding the [OUTPUT clause](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177564.aspx) like so:

```
DELETE Sales.ShoppingCartItem
OUTPUT DELETED.* 
WHERE ShoppingCartID = 20621;
```

This will output the deletes rows.

To avoid SQL injections, you should use SQL parameters